# Why is self.splitViewController == nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a new iOS 8 project using Xcode 6's `Master Detail Application` template. I have not changed the code in any way.

When setting a breakpoint in `DetailViewController.m` and inspecting the `self.splitViewController` property as shown in the following screenshot, it returns `nil`.

[image]

**Why is that?**

According to the Apple UISplitViewController [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html), `self.splitViewController` should return the nearest `SplitViewController`:

> If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a split view
>   controller, this property contains the owning split view controller.
>   This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a
>   split view controller.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if you ever figured this out, but I just had this issue and found what was wrong and looks similar to your case.

The splitViewController property does not get configured until after viewDidLoad. If by accident your code using it gets triggered before viewDidLoad then the value will be nil.

I notice in your code example that configureView is called from setDetailItem. If that is per chance being called from prepareForSegue then viewDidLoad will not have happened yet resulting in a nil for splitViewController property value inside configureView. So code has to be run after after [super viewDidLoad] has completed.

Comment: After super.viewDidLoad didn't work for me. But either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear works.

Comment: It’s good practice to put a check of isViewLoaded before the call to configureView within setDetailItem. Otherwise you may unwittingly cause the view to load at a less optimal time. If for example you call self.view for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `setDetailItem` in the template is missing a crucial check of `isViewLoaded`:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(Event *)detailItem {
    if (_detailItem == detailItem) {
        return;
    }
    _detailItem = detailItem;

    if(self.isViewLoaded){
        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}
```

This allows setting of the detail before the view is loaded (like in `prepareForSegue`) when the things you require would otherwise be `nil` and  also prevents it accidentally loading the view, if you were using `self.view` inside `configureView` for something.